# PHP: Are arrays passed to a function automatically Immutable?

Tags: php, arrays

I have been driving myself crazy with this for the past half hour and have checked various sites to try and find a solution, and what everybody is suggesting is what I have tried.

I pass an array to my function to write some data back to the client, however PHP always complains that a key that doesn't exist is trying to be accessed.  This is fine, but by default I thought if you try to set a value for an unspecified key, PHP would generate that key and add it to the array:

```
if(!isset($data['payload']))
   $data['payload'] = 'No data for this resource';
```

The only reason I can think for this not working is that the Array is immutable and therefore cannot be appended to.

```
private function _setResponse($data, $statusCode = 200)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 " . $statusCode . " " . $this->_getStatus($statusCode));

    if(!isset($data['payload']))
        $data['payload'] = 'No data for this resource';

    // Set the response object
    $response = array(
                        'response' => $statusCode . " : " . $this->_getStatus($statusCode),
                        'data' => $data['payload']
                     );

    return json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: What does your function look like? And it will generate a key, the passed variable just has a local scope.

Comment: Sorry, appended to question

Comment: Are you sure this is where you get the warning? You should check (add...) the exact error message and see where it is occurring exactly as this should not give you any problems.

Comment: `var_dump($data)` inside your function, to see what really got passed in. php doesn't have "immutable", but you should learn between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value...

Comment: I'm unclear what the question is. Are you saying that **without `isset`**, you get that warning? Or are you saying that the array **outside the function** does not contain the new key you added inside the function?

Comment: The error is thrown at the `$data['payload'] = 'No data for this resource'` line. Passing by reference fixed the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not make any sense.

Comment: Provide the *exact, verbatim* error message please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass by reference if you want to modify the array without explicitly returning it at the end of the function. Change your function as such:

```
private function _setResponse(&$data, $statusCode = 200)
```

You can read more on [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) in the PHP manual.